# SAF (storage access framework) for mp3 player

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

I'm using the [libaums](https://github.com/magnusja/libaums) library to access mp3 files from a usb drive.

As I see it, (because I dont want to copy all mp3 at the beginning to the smartphone) I HAVE TO use the SAF. But I actually only need the Uris of the files, I know where the files are located.

1) Is there a way to use SAF to get the Uris, without prompting the user about it?

2) And if I HAVE TO ask the user, is there a way to at least let him select a folder and retrieve all the Uris of the files in that folder?

Thansk in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to use SAF to get the Uris, without prompting the user about it?

Not really. You could ask the user to provide you with the root via `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` or the `StorageVolume` APIs, then attempt to use `DocumentFile` to traverse the tree to your desired location.

> And if I HAVE TO ask the user, is there a way to at least let him select a folder and retrieve all the Uris of the files in that folder?

Use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and `DocumentFile`.